# Call a jquery function on ajax returned html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a scenario where I have a code like this

HTML

`<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" id="slider1">`

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#slider1").Slider();
});
```

when document loads, some stuff is done to my input box by my `Slider()` function.
The issue am facing is that, am replacing the same input box html on ajax return and can't get my  `Slider()` called.

AJAX RETURN

```
...
success: function(data) {
   // This was removing the wrapper element, all the other calls
   // to $('#slider1') were doing nothing
   //$("#slider1").remove();
   $("#slider1").html('<input type="submit" value="{{ some variable }}" name="submit" id="slider1">');
}
...
```

I was thinking of calling the `Slider()` function inside the input box so that it will be called,

something like:

```
    $("#slider1").html('<input type="submit" callSliderFunction="Slider()"  value="{{ some variable }}" name="submit" id="slider1">');
```

Is it possible to call it there? If not How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: I'm totally confused to see this. you have an input type `submit` with id `slider1` and on `ajax success` you have remove element whose id `slider1` and again you have added some code... `$("#slider1").html("your html")`. Just think about what have you done. Can you really do this ?? `$(input).html()`. Can you please explain me little bit?

Comment: I have removed it, though that's not the problem am asking about. My problem is calling the function.

Comment: Whether it's the problem you are asking about or not, it is a problem, questions should be useful to others, not just you.

Comment: That's very true, but I meant that removing it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just call .Slider() again after you add it to the page in the success function.

```
success: function(data) {
   $("#slider1").remove();
   $("#slider1").html('<input type="submit" value="{{ some variable }}" name="submit" id="slider1">');
   $("#slider1").Slider();
}
```

As Juan pointed out, you can't call .html() on #slider1 once you .remove() it. From looking at what you have, its my guess that you're trying to change the value of the #slider1, in which case it would be simpler to do just that

```
success: function(data) {
   $("#slider1").attr("value", "{{ some variable }}");
   $("#slider1").Slider();
}
```

Comment: `$("#slider1").remove()` will remove `#slider1`,I don't think you should do that

Comment: That's true, I just copied what OP had. It don't see the purpose of .removing it then adding it back with .html...

Comment: The point is that after calling `remove()`, there will be no more `#slider1` and the functions won't do anything

Comment: Yup, I understand that. I copied the OP's code which was erroneous. But that's not the problem he's asking about.

Comment: @Matt, whether it's the problem he asked about or not, you have an answer that does not work. Please update the answer so we don't have an answer that is marked correct with incorrect info. Answers at stack overflow are supposed to be useful to others, not just the one who asked the question http://jsfiddle.net/y7xKf/

Answer (score 0):

Just call it like you did when the document loaded after you have changed the `html`.

```
$("#slider1").Slider();
```

Comment: I think it needs to be `$('#slider1').Slider()`; `$.html`  will return the new content, the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it after you've setup the HTML

```
success: function(data) {
  var wrapper = $("#slider1");
  wrapper.html('<input type="submit" value="{{ some variable }}" name="submit"   id="slider1">');
  wrapper.Slider();
}
```